# Не отрабатывает скрипт после возврата на страницу. Только в Сафари

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, safari

Есть drug-and-drop форма, в которую кидается пдф-файл, появляется прелоадер на время загрузки документа, по завершению происходит редирект в инструмент редактирования pdf-файла. Если находясь в инструменте кликнуть на кнопку "назад" в браузере - прелоадер не исчезает. Проблема только в Сафари.

Функция скрытия прелоадера предельно проста - просто при загрузке страницы убирается класс, к нему подвязаны необходимые стили.

```
function clearPreloader() {
  var preloader = document.getElementById('dropzoneFormPreloader');
  preloader.classList.remove('active');
}
clearPreloader();
```

Я проверял - функция вообще не стартует. Повторюсь, проблема только в Сафари. С чем это может быть связано, и возможно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: Такс у меня сразу несколько вопросов)) Ф-ия сама запускается вообще? Если да то элемент `#dropzoneFormPreloader` находится? Пробовали подождать полной загрузки страницы в своей ф-ии?

Comment: @EzioMercer, спасибо за ваш комментарий, проблему уже решил. Связана с тем, что сафари кеширует страницы, здесь более подробно)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046/the-safari-back-button-problem